# Jupyter notebookのメニューリストに関して

Tags: jupyter-notebook

画像で添付した各メニューに対しての説明を教えてください。

Code → コード記載
Markdown → ●●
Raw NBConvert → ●●
Heading → ●●

[image: リストの役割を教えてください。]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Code
  ソースコードを記載する部分です。
- Markdown
  ソースコードではない一般の文章を記載する部分で、Markdown記法が利用可能です。
- Raw NBConvert
  Markdown **ではない** 文章を記載する部分のようです。ドキュメントでの言及を見つけられませんでした。NBSphinx関連に記載があるかもしれません。
- Heading
  ヘッダー（見出し）です。

https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.html